# MySQL Select groups of records based on change in value by comparing to previous group

Tags: mysql

Given the table, I am trying to select groups of records and sum the last column `Class` in each group.  The rules of the grouping are slightly complicated and rows need to be compared to each other.

```
|| Seq || Time || Spec || Class  
|| 1   || 8:05 || 0    || 5  
|| 2   || 8:06 || 1    || 5  
|| 3   || 8:07 || 2    ||10  
|| 4   || 8:08 || 4    ||10  
|| 5   || 8:09 || 3    || 5  
|| 6   || 8:10 || 2    || 5  
|| 7   || 8:11 || 6    || 5  
|| 8   || 8:12 || 6    ||15
```

I need to group records based on the change in value (increase or decrease) in the `Spec` column.  The required change in value is 2.  So starting with row 1, the `Spec` is `0`.  It doesn’t increase by at least `2` until row 3.  This is a valid group and I need to sum the `Class` field.  The expected output is `StartTime`, `StartSpec`, `EndTime`, `EndSpec`, and `TotalClass`.

To determine the next group, I need to measure the change in value with the last row used in the previous group. As you can see, row 4 has immediately increased by 2 and so this one row is a valid group.

Expected Output:

```
||StartTime || StartSpec || EndTime || EndSpec || TotalClass  
||  8:05    ||    0      ||   8:07  ||    2    ||    20  
||  8:08    ||    4      ||   8:08  ||    4    ||    10  
||  8:09    ||    3      ||   8:10  ||    2    ||    10  
||  8:11    ||    6      ||   8:11  ||    6    ||     5
```

Comment: If the `8:09` row has a `spec` value of 3, then why doesn't it also get its own record in your expected output?

Comment: Because the last record used (8:08) has a spec of 4. Compare that to 8:09 which has a spec of 3. `The required change in value is 2`

Comment: Your math is not clear to me, sorry.

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo answered correctly. I deleted my comment as I was looking at the wrong row. I need to compare to the last row used in the previous group. 4 to 3 is only a change of 1.

Comment: You are not clear. Select *which* "groups of records"? What have you tried? What parts can you do? Please read & act on [mcve] and hits from googling 'stackexchange homework'. PS Use code format (eg indent 4 spaces) to format tables.

Comment: This is not a job for SQL. Probably it can be done in MySQL using variables. I would definitely do it in the client code, no matter which language you are using, it is definitely more appropriate than SQL for such processing.

Comment: I think the first part of the problem can, and should, be done in sql, using variables. The display part can, and probably should, be handled in application code.

Comment: @nodoze What happens at the row `8` (8:12), based on the rules described it should make a group of its own (as the previous row - 7, makes a closed one-row group, just like row 4), but it is not included in the `Expected Output` for some reason.

Comment: @zeppelin the value of the last row in the previous group is 6. 6 to 6 is a change of 0.  2 is required.

Comment: @axiac the main problem with grouping in the client code is that I must commit to a rate of change upfront. I need the ability to query the raw data at a later time to investigate different rates of change. In this example it is 2, but I will need to investigate 3, 4, 5 etc. The various future rates are unknown at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done by using some intermediate variables, to detect the first and the last row in a group, as illustrated below.

Note that this will "auto-close" the last group, if it is not closed yet.

Also note, that for the use-cases like that, application-level solution
might be a more elegant option (as noted in the comments already).

Another option is to compute an explicit group discriminator (i.e. "gid"), at the data insertion time, and store it in the table itself, so that you can then query data in a standard way, w/o relying on any variables.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(startTime) as startTime,
    MAX(startSpec) as startSpec,
    MAX(endTime) as endTime,
    MAX(endSpec) as endSpec,
    SUM(class) as totalClass
FROM (
    SELECT 
        /* Detect first and last rows in a group (when ordered by "seq") */
        @first as isFirst,
        @last:=(ABS(@prev-spec)>1 OR seq=(SELECT MAX(seq) FROM groups)) as isLast,    

        /* If this is a first row, set "startTime" and "startSpec" */
        IF(@first,time,NULL) as startTime,
        IF(@first,spec,NULL) as startSpec,

        /* If this is a last row, set "endTime" and "endSpec" */
        IF(@last,time,NULL) as endTime,
        IF(@last,spec,NULL) as endSpec,

        /* Start the next group */
        IF(@last,@prev:=spec,NULL) as nextPrev,
        IF(@last,(@gid:=@gid+1)-1,@gid) as gid,

        /* Flip "first" */
        @first:=@last as nextIsFirst,

        /* Row "class" */
        class
    FROM 

    /* Declare some variables */
    (SELECT @first:=TRUE,@last:=FALSE,@prev:=0,@gid:=0) init 

    CROSS JOIN Groups ORDER BY seq
) labeled GROUP BY gid;
```

Comment: thank you and trying the solution now. The main issue with determining groups at insertion time is that we need to query the data later, using different values of "change". Although in this example the rate of change required is 2, we may need to query using a value of 3 or 4 etc.  On that topic, is this code where that determination is made? `(ABS(@prev-spec)>1`

Comment: thanks for the help, this is really close. my only concern is the final grouping pulls `8:12 || 6 || 8:12 || 6 || 15` however this is not a valid group. the value in the last row in the previous group is 6. So from 6 to 6 the change is zero. Required change is 2.

Comment: @nodoze I've intentionally added `OR seq=(SELECT MAX(seq) FROM groups)`, so that the last "unclosed" group would be "auto-closed" and included in the results. As that is not what you want, just remove it, and add `HAVING SUM(isLast) > 0` to the outer query, to completely exclude it.